# ComputeLibrary data type templates

Tags: c++, templates, arm, simd

In the [ARM ComputeLibrary](https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary), we can have a Tensor object of various types.  When choosing the type of Tensors, we pass the type to the initaliser of the Tensor's allocator, such as float32 here:

```
my_tensor.allocator()->init(armcl::TensorInfo(shape_my_tensor, 1, armcl::DataType::F32));
```

A better introduction to the topic of tensor allocation can be found [here](https://arm-software.github.io/ComputeLibrary/v18.11/architecture.https://arm-software.github.io/ComputeLibrary/v18.11/architecture.xhtml#S4_6_4_working_with_objectsxhtml#S4_6_4_working_with_objects).

There are several ARMCL types to choose from ([see here for a list](https://arm-software.github.io/ComputeLibrary/v17.04/namespacearm__compute.xhtml#ad8ed01ff3ff33333d8e19db4d2818bb6)).  Notice that the ComputeLibrary types are not primitive ones, though one can easily copy primitive typed data to them.

However, when writing templated C++ code, where one can have functions defined for arbitrary types, this "type choice which is not a type" creates a design problem.

Say I want to write a function that takes data of primitive types such as `int`, `float`, or `double`.  In the templated function, this type would be referred to as being of type `T` (or whatever).

Now say I want to copy this data to an ARMCL Tensor within the scope of the templated function.  This tensor needs to be initalised to the correct datatype.  We need this datatype to be a good fit for the type `T`, so if `T` is a `float`, then our ARMCL should be of type `F32`, if `T` is an `int` then our tensor should be `S8`, etc.

We need some sort of mapping between primitive types, and the ARMCL types.

Would a "nice" and sensible approach be to have a utility function that takes the type `T` and maybe using a switch statement, and something like `std::is_same`.  The switch statement would then return the appropriate ARM Compute Library DataType object for `T`?  Or is there a different approach that might be more elegant?

I have been looking around [the docs](https://arm-software.github.io/ComputeLibrary/v18.11/index.xhtml) to see if this is already handled, but to no avail yet.  If it isn't handled, then perhaps this is not a specific to ARMCL question, and is broader in scope.

Comment: _"T and maybe using a switch statement, and something like `std::is_same`."_ No, that approach would fail, since `switch()` is evaluated at runtime.The usual approach for such things is SFINAE and specializations, which can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: My eyes have been opened to a bigger world, having never heard of SFINAE before.  will investigate.  thanks for the explanation of why my approach might not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... armcl types are, if I understand correctly, enum values.

So a possible approach is a template struct, with full specializations, with a `value` in it.

I mean... something as

```
template <typename>
struct typeMap;

template <>
struct typeMap<int>
 { static constexpr auto value = armcl::DataType::S8; };

template <>
struct typeMap<float>
 { static constexpr auto value = armcl::DataType::F32; };

// other cases
```

You can use it as follows

```
template <typename T>
void foo ()
 { bar(typeMap<T>::value); }
```

Comment: this is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for, thanks!  The typeMap struct is inherently reusable, and easy to add to.  Good pattern